# AVContentKeySessionDelegate methods not called

Tags: ios, swift, drm, brightcove, avcontentkeysession

Implemented the delegate methods of  **AVContentKeySessionDelegate** within my ViewController.swift in my iOS application which is to play drm content using Brightcove SDK.

### Code snippet :

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, AVContentKeySessionDelegate, BCOVPlaybackControllerDelegate {  
    var contentKeySession: AVContentKeySession!
      .
      . 
   func getVideo() { 
     // fetching video using an API call
        .
        .
     let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
     self.contentKeySession = AVContentKeySession(keySystem: .fairPlayStreaming)
     self.contentKeySession?.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
     self.contentKeySession?.addContentKeyRecipient(asset)
   }

  //MARK: - AVContentKeySessionDelegate Methods
  func contentKeySession(_ session: AVContentKeySession, didProvide keyRequest: AVContentKeyRequest) {
    handleKeyRequest(keyRequest: keyRequest)
  }

  func contentKeySession(_ session: AVContentKeySession, contentKeyRequest keyRequest: AVContentKeyRequest, didFailWithError err: Error) {
    print(err)
  }

  func contentKeySession(_ session: AVContentKeySession, contentKeyRequestDidSucceed keyRequest: AVContentKeyRequest) {
    print(keyRequest)
  }
 }
```

### Issue

1. None of these delegate methods are getting invoked.
2. Also, noticed an error in the Xcode console saying :  NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 (*Allow arbitrary loads is set to true in App Transport Settings in Info.plist*)

Comment: When you saw an error with -1002 code in iOS FairPlay, this usually means that you didn't get the content key. You already found the answer. Congrats. Best.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the intent of `self.contentKeySession.processContentKeyRequest` is to cache the content key. In theory, the content session key delegate should be called as long as the content is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
self.contentKeySession.processContentKeyRequest(withIdentifier: "<identifier>", initializationData: nil, options: nil)
```

fixed the issue. When the request to process content key is made, the delegate methods are getting invoked.